# Как занести большое количество информации в MySQL

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Доброго времени.

Вопрос с одной стороны детский, поэтому прошу не плеваться в меня) Я решил сделать игрушку покемончики, мими, такие зверьки, думаю все знают что это за фрукти. В этих зверьков есть свои типы, например:

- нормальный
- огненный
- водный

и т.п. Также, у этих покемонов есть свои атаки, аналогично:

- нормальные
- огненные
- водные

и т.п. Вот, и когда водный покемон сражается против огненного, то понятно, что водный имеет преимущество (Ну понятно да, что вода делает пш-пш на огонь и он тушится)

Так вот, комбинаций таких примерно 3000 тысячи.

http://pokemondb.net/type/dual - Весь список

Сверху это какую атаку использовал покемон, а сбоку это какой тип покемона сражается против какого, например:

*Водный покемон сражается против огненного, использует водную атаку и урон x2*

В базе у меня есть 4 колонки:

- type1  - Тип первого покемона
- type2  - Тип второго покемона
- type3  - Тип атаки которую использует первый покемон
- damage - Урон, например удваивается

Теперь вопрос, можно ли как то продублировать с того сайта информацию и засунуть в базу? 
Только не вручную, а это это займет просто нереально много времени.

Помогите пожалуйста, страдаю уже целый день.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: там, конечно, уже дали конкретный ответ, но я бы решил задачу через стандартный symfony/dom-crawler и, на всякий, промежуточный yaml-файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнить в отладочной консоли:

```
$('td')
    .map(function(){ return $(this).attr('title') + ' (' + $(this).text() + ')' })
    .get()
    .join("\n")
```

Получить:

```
...
Normal → Normal/Fire = normal effectiveness ()
Fire → Normal/Fire = not very effective (½)
Water → Normal/Fire = super-effective (2)
Electric → Normal/Fire = normal effectiveness ()
Grass → Normal/Fire = not very effective (½)
Ice → Normal/Fire = not very effective (½)
Fighting → Normal/Fire = super-effective (2)
Poison → Normal/Fire = normal effectiveness ()
Ground → Normal/Fire = super-effective (2)
Flying → Normal/Fire = normal effectiveness ()
Psychic → Normal/Fire = normal effectiveness ()
Bug → Normal/Fire = not very effective (½)
Rock → Normal/Fire = super-effective (2)
Ghost → Normal/Fire = no effect (0)
Dragon → Normal/Fire = normal effectiveness ()
Dark → Normal/Fire = normal effectiveness ()
Steel → Normal/Fire = not very effective (½)
Fairy → Normal/Fire = not very effective (½)
...
```

Ну уж а строчки в SQL как-нибудь сами распарсите. :)